# $f(x) = x\sin x$ $\varepsilon - \delta$ proof verification

Tags: proof-verification, epsilon-delta

We have the function $f(x) = x\sin x$

and we want to show that $f(x)\to0$ for $x\to0$.

We want to find a $\delta$ where $\|x \sin x-0\|<\varepsilon$ and $\|x-0\|<\delta$

We know that $|\sin x| \leq |x|$

so therefore $x|\sin x| \leq x^2$

we now have the pattern $\|x-0\|^2$

and we can choose a $\delta = \sqrt{\varepsilon}$

Proof done.

Is this a valid proof? Did I make any mistakes? And if so, how do I fix it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: That looks fine, but put the $x$ inside the absolute value sign (i.e., $|x\sin(x)|\le x^2$).

Comment: @MarkViola Thanks mate.

Comment: "We want to find a δ where ∥xsinx−0∥<ε and ∥x−0∥<δ"  As written that is no sense.  There is no $\delta$ where $|x-0| < \delta$ as we can always pick an $|x| \ge \delta$.  And $\epsilon$ has not been defined.  And we can always pick an integer $k$ where $x=2k\pi + \frac \pi 2 \ge \epsilon$.  You don't mean what you wrote.  Rewrite it to what you actually mean.

Comment: "We know that |sinx|≤|x|"  Why? "so therefore x|sinx|≤x2"  Make that $|x\sin x| \le x^2$.

Comment: "we now have the pattern $∥x−0∥^2$"  I honestly do not know what you mean by "pattern".  Are you trying to say we now have $|x \sin x - 0| \le |x-0|^2$ for all $x$?

Comment: The product of continuous functions is continuous.